# MVC Code First referencing existing table getting error {"Invalid object name 'dbo.TableNames'."}

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am new to MVC 4 and Entity Framework, but have successfully been able to create new tables using migration, as well as seeding them.  My problem is now I need to access a table in the database, that already exists.  I am not able to create this table via code as this table is created and populated by a process outside of my development arena.  I am getting error: {"Invalid object name 'dbo.Markets'."}, however the correct name of the table is Market, not Markets.  I have added    ToTable("Market", "app"); in my mapping file, but I'm still getting the same error.  What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include some code that is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) else nobody will be able to answer what your error is.

Answer (score 0):

Create the model class for Market.

use a table annotation (on the model)

```
[Table("Market")]
public class Market
{
}
```

You can alternatively remove pluralization from the whole database (in the context file) with:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```